# Kafka offset getting Lost while Processing the Streams

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, hadoop-streaming

I am using KafkaUtils.createDirectStream Kafka API to consume the messages and then i am processing the messages to store in Hive.Due to failure accessing Hive metastore, sometimes the job is failing. 
Upon restarting i am seeing that it always starts reading from the "Latest" message(because in my code auto.offset.reset=latest) instead of reading from the last committed message. It is losing the offset in this scenario.
Thus i want to store the offset after the entire processing is completed so that i can retrieve it when there's failure in retrieving the message.

Please suggest how can i store the offset in Kafka using using KafkaUtils.createDirectStream making sure that the entire Kafka job is completed.

Comment: checkpointing may help. [apache spark checkpointing](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing)

Comment: You can try HasOffsetRanges, this is used to access offset ranges in RDDs generated by the direct Kafka DStream.

 `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...).foreachRDD { rdd =>
      val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
       
    }`

Comment: Thanks for your response Teena. I implemented the above in my code, but i am getting Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Object of org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream is being serialized possibly as a part of closure of an RDD operation. This is because the DStream object is being referred to from within the closure. Please rewrite the RDD operation inside this DStream to avoid this. This has been enforced to avoid bloating of Spark tasks with unnecessary objects.